# firefox portable: doesnt open links from other applications

Tags: firefox, portable

I'm having a very annoying problem: I'm using Firefox 4 Portable on my office PC, everything is ok except when clicking links from my email programm or messenger. Firefox (already running) won't open them but instead displays an error message:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding.

I think the problem is that I previously used the normal version of Firefox on that machine, which i removed - and the system won't recognize the portable version properly.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like problem is due to portable version, cause email client opens links in your default internet browser. Maybe you need to **completely** delete your previous version of normal Firefox. [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) is free very useful. Or you can go to run/regedit HKEY/LOCAL/MACHINE/Software, HKEY/CURRENT/USER/Software and delete all occurrences about Firefox. System could think that Firefox is your default browaser but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same on a much more recent FF 31. With an installed (non-portable) Firefox. — [See the last of the common causes on mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use#Common_causes).

In essence, don't start your default profile with `-no remote`. You may specifiy a `-profile`path. No problem with that.